# Agile Toolkit manipulating Grid column content

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

Just started using ATK4 and appreciating it very much so far, but not sure how to do this...

What I am trying to accomplish:

I am outputting a query's results to a grid, one of the fields is 'status', the data will either be '-1' or '1'.
Instead of outputting -1 or 1 to the column, how do I output an HTML snippet (or whatever I need to to get what I want) instead that shows a different icon for each value?
In short:

In column 'status':

- if the value is -1, display iconDown.gif;
- if the value is 1, display iconUp.gif

Code so far:

```
class page_showlist extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $q=$this->api->db->dsql();
    $q->table('remote_system')
            ->join('customers.id','customer_id')
            ->field('customer_id')
            ->field('ip')
            ->field('nickname')
            ->field('name','customers')
            ->field('status')
    ;

    $grid = $this->add('Grid');

    $grid->addColumn('text','status')->makeSortable();
    $grid->addColumn('text','name')->makeSortable();
    $grid->addColumn('text','ip');
    $grid->addColumn('text','nickname');
    $grid->addButton('Reload Grid')->js('click',$grid->js()->reload());
    $grid->addQuickSearch(array('name'));
    $grid->setSource( $q );
    }
```

}

Any pointers/tips?

Comment: This can be accomplished with Grid formatters. You'll have to write your own formatter function. And one question - why you don't use Model?

Comment: I have a CRUD on the admin side for maintaining the info, I intend for this to be a read-only version of the info. This *seemed* the most natural way to go, but as stated above, just getting started with ATK4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add column with icons in Grid you can use custom template.

In one of my projects I do like this:

```
$url = $this->api->pm->base_url . $this->api->locateURL('template', 'images/');
$grid->addColumn('template', 'type', false)
    ->setTemplate('<img src="' . $url . 'icon_object_<?$type?>.png">');
```

It'll use model field named `type` (in your case use `status`) and show icons in that column. Icon source URL is generated dynamically and it'll search for image files in your `template/images` directory named **icon_object_XXX.png** where **XXX** value will be taken from field `type` value.

In my case `type` is like this: `array('building','apartment','land','garage')` etc.

And one more thing - you should start using Models whenever possible! That way you'll ease your life later when your project becomes bigger. Also can have extra security (conditions, etc.) with them.

Comment: Thanks! Great info and explanation.

Comment: In year 2013 when this answer was created template tag string was `<? ... ?>`.
Currently in ATK version 4.3 you have to use curly braces instead `{ ... }`.